# How to use json files availiable with Qt Plugin classes

Tags: c++, qt, qtplugin

Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "descComponentIID" FILE "file.json")

How to utilize the json file for configuring a component.
My Purpose is to store the configuration of a component like if
its a paint canvas component then storing the size of the canvas
or the background colour of the component?

Answer (score 0):

//Suppose A JSON file is created
Example Test.json

{
"Name" : "Test",
"Version" : "1.0.1",
"CompatVersion" : "1.0.0",
"Vendor" : "My Company",
"Copyright" : "(C) 2016 MyCompany",
"License" : [
"This is a default license bla",
"blubbblubb",
"end of terms"
]
}

//Now Access metadata with the PluingLoader Which is used to load the

QJsonObject QPluginLoader::metaData() const

//The QJsonObject can be resursively traversed and QJsonValue can be

QJsonValue  take(QLatin1String key)

Answer (score 0):

I will post a small draft to help me provide an explanation.

`nmplugin.json`

```
{
    "name": "nm",
    "arguments": "--some-args"
}
```

You must access the "Metadata" key before any other entry in the json file. Don't forget to test the returned `QJsonValue` with `isUndefined()` to be on the safe side.

```
QJsonObject object{ loader->metaData().value("MetaData").toObject() };
qDebug() << object.value("name"); // Will print "nm"
```